# MySQL: Inserting datetime value (including timezone) results in wrong column value

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-insert, timestamp-with-timezone

Since I couldn't find a similar thread, here's my issue.
My table "test_table" consists of a datetime column "timestamp_column".
The MySQL server is configured to run in timezone GMT+1.

Now, I am inserting the following two rows:

```
insert into test_table (timestamp_column) values ('2024-03-18 01:03:57.621000+00:00');
insert into test_table (timestamp_column) values ('2024-03-18 01:05:32.210000+00:00');
```

Result:

```
select timestamp_column from test_table;
```

```
2024-03-18 01:03:58
2024-03-18 02:05:32
```

So basically, since the MySQL server runs in GMT+1, the conversion from 01:05:32 to 02:05:32 is correct. But, why wouldn't it also convert the first row to 02:03:58?

It's obvious that the fractional part causes this issue - but why doesn't the error occur consistently?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: What is the local timezone of the server?

Comment: Ideally you should have the server locked to UTC as otherwise you encounter all kinds of utterly bizarre time-zone issues, especially when moving data from one server to another.

Comment: @Charlieface It is also set in a GMT+1 zone.

Comment: Is that during the time when Daylight Saving Time changes in your country?

Comment: Looks like parsing bug. https://dbfiddle.uk/zCFTETfH PS. Timezone recognition was implemented in ver. 8.0.19.